# Calculating sum for decimal values via Core Data not working properly?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsdecimalnumber

first time I post to this round, so please bear with me if I don't follow all the rules properly.

I am writing an app for the iPhone (OS 3.1) and am trying to write some code which lets me add decimals. I have a Core Data entity called SimpleItem with a amount attribute. Here is the test case I wrote:

```
// Create and configure objects
    SimpleItem *si1 = [self createSimpleItem:@"si1"];
    si1.amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1000 exponent:0 isNegative:NO];
    SimpleItem *si2 = [self createSimpleItem:@"s12"];
    si2.amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:2000 exponent:0 isNegative:NO];
    // Need to save prior to fetching results with NSDictionaryResultType (known limitation)
    [self save]; 

    // Describe fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SimpleItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

    NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"amount"];
//  For whatever reason, evaluating this expression here is absolutely not working. Probably decimals aren't handled properly.
    NSExpression *sumAmountExpression = [NSExpression 
                                         expressionForFunction:@"max:"
                                         arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

    NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    [expressionDescription setName:@"amount"];
    [expressionDescription setExpression:sumAmountExpression];
    [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];

    // Fetch the amounts
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *array = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

If I execute this code through otest and debug it, I get an exception when the fetch request is executed: "-[NSDecimalNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance."

Just evaluating the keyPathExpression without the aggregate function works fine, though.

The [reference documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1) shows exactly the same example so I'm wondering what I am doing wrong. Or could this be just a bug?

All the best,
Harald

Comment: I encountered this too; think this is a bug in Core Data because it works in the SQL store, but not the in-memory one. I'm going to file this in radar when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had this problem before. IIRC, the problem is that you've set <strike>your fetch result type to `NSDictionaryResultType` but you're receiving it in an `NSArray`. Try switching the fetch result type to `NSManagedObjectResultType` which does return an array.</strike> All the examples in the docs use the default `NSManagedObjectResultType`.

In any case, the error message clearly results from an NSDecimal object being sent an array's `count` message. You could confirm this by trapping the result in an `id`. eg:

```
id *genericObj = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];  
NSLog("returned object=%@",genericObj);
NSLog("returned object class=%@",[genericObj class]);
```

Comment: When specifying a `NSDictionaryResultType` you will receive an array containing one object via `executeFetchRequest:error:`.

Comment: That's what I get for winging it from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for letting me know. The thing is that I actually don't want to use managed objects. After all, I am interested in the amounts only and this is what I get with the dictionary.

Also, trying to investigate the issue as you described didn't work as executing the fetch request immediately fails and I don't get anything back.

Any other ideas? Is there any other possibility to get aggregate values? Any "best practices"? At the moment I do the following (continuation of the code above):

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    [expressionDescription setName:@"amount"];
    [expressionDescription setExpression:keyPathExpression];
    [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];

```
// Fetch the amounts
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (array == nil) {
    STFail(@"Fetch request could not be completed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
STAssertEquals([array count], (NSUInteger) 2, @"Number of fetched objects != 2");

// Manually calculate the sum
NSDecimalNumber *sum = nil;
for (NSDictionary * dictionary in array) {
    NSDecimalNumber *amount = (NSDecimalNumber *) [dictionary valueForKey:@"amount"];
    if (!sum) {
        sum = amount;
    } else {
        sum = [sum decimalNumberByAdding:amount];
    }
}
STAssertNotNil(sum, @"Sum is nil");
STAssertTrue([sum isEqualToNumber:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:3000 exponent:0 isNegative:NO]], 
               @"Sum != 3000: %@", sum);
```

Regards,
Harald

Comment: Hey Harald, please don't post your responses as an answer to your question.  Instead, you should use the "add comment" feature to directly reply to answers/comments and edit your question with additional information as you find it.

Comment: You need a certain amount of reputation to comment, updating the original question is fine though... just add a new section with the updated info so you can still see the original question

Answer (score 0):

Copying your given source to a new iPhone project and running that in the simulator worked fine here. I was compiling against the 3.1.2 SDK on Snow Leopard.

This is what I used for the data model:

[model description http://homepage.mac.com/aclark78/.Public/Pictures/test%20model.png](http://homepage.mac.com/aclark78/.Public/Pictures/test%20model.png)

There must be something else going on causing your issue. Can you describe your model or simplify it further?

Comment: See my comment to the original question; I were you using an SQL store?